# In Sybase, Convert sql timestamp to unixtime

Tags: sql, timestamp, type-conversion, sybase, unix-timestamp

I'm using the Sybase database, How do I change SQL timestamp which appears in my database in form like: `2012-03-23 11:27:04.870000` to unixtime.

I want to be able to do something like this in sql:

```
select time1, unix_time_function(time1) as time1_to_unixtime from mytable
```

Can it be done?

Comment: you could use select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-03-23 11:27:04.870000'); for mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), UNIX time is the number of seconds elapsed since 1st Jan 1970 (not including leap seconds).

Bearing that in mind (and if I haven't completely lost it) it should just be the difference between 1970-01-01 and your time, in seconds:

```
SELECT time1,
       Datediff(SECOND, '1970-01-01', time1) AS time1_to_unixtime
FROM   mytable
```

I'm not sure whether `DateDiff` takes leap seconds into account, if not, there might be some adjustments needed.

Documentation for `DateDiff` in Sybase is [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks139.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There is the `convert` function in Sybase that has different options to convert time like

```
select convert(char(20),getdate(),101) --- value from 101 to 123
```

Check [this article in the Sybase Infocenter](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks125.htm).